# Django Access Token Matching Query Does Not Exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, oauth

I have the following code I am trying to test:

```
def customer_add_order(request):
    """
        params: 
            access_token
            restaurant_id
            address
            order_details(json format), example:
                [{"meal_id": 1, "quantity":2}, {"meal_id": 2, "quantity":3}]
            stripe_token

        return:
            {"status": "success"}

    """
    if request.method == "POST":
        #Get token
        access_token = AccessToken.objects.get(token = request.POST.get("access_token"),
            expires__gt = timezone.now())
        #Get profile
        customer = access_token.user.customer

        # Check if customer has a order that is not delivered
        if Order.objects.filter(customer = customer).exclude(status = Order.DELIVERED):
            return JsonResponse({"status": "fail", "error": "Your Last Order must be completed"})

        # Check Address
        if not request.POST("address"):
            return JsonResponse({"status": "failed", "error": "Address is required."})

        # Ger Order Details
        order_details = json.load(request.POST["order_details"])

        order_total = 0
        for meal in order_details:
            order_total += Meal.objects.get(id = meal["meal_id"]).price * meal[quantity]

        if len(order_details)>0:
            # Step 1 - Create an Order
            order = Order.objects.create(
                customer = customer,
                restaurant_id = request.POST["restaurant_id"],
                total = order_total,
                status = Order.PENDING,
                address = request.POST["address"]
            )
            # Step 2 - Create Order details
            for meal in order_details:
                OrderDetails.objects.create(
                    order = order,
                    meal_id = meal["meal_id"],
                    quantity = meal["quantity"],
                    sub_total = Meal.objects.get(id = meal["meal_id"]).price * meal["quantity"]
                )
            return JsonResponse({"status": "success"})
```

I enter the params in Postman, and use an access token that shows valid in django, and it hasn't expired. I am using the rest framework and the function is for API.

I use the following function for creating Access Token:

```
def create_user_by_type(backend, user, response, *args, **kwargs):
    request = backend.strategy.request_data()
    if backend.name == 'facebook':
        avatar = 'https://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?type=large' % response['id']

    if request.get("user_type") == "driver" and not Driver.objects.filter(user_id=user.id):
        Driver.objects.create(user_id=user.id, avatar = avatar)
    elif not Customer.objects.filter(user_id=user.id):
        Customer.objects.create(user_id=user.id, avatar = avatar)
```

Also, the line `if request.get("user_type") == "driver" and not Driver.objects.filter(user_id=user.id):` previously had an error because I had it in an outdated format `request["user_type"]`. Not sure if this is correct syntax for what I want to do, but I can create Access Tokens through Postman.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I was using the params in Postman to enter the Access Token and other information, instead it should in in 'body' with form-data selected.

Comment: For futures OAuth testing, I'd suggest https://oauth.tools. It's build for this kinda thing.